# coded ui tests : How to set folder path needed in an explorer browser for folder?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, folderbrowserdialog

I'm writting Coded UI tests for a desktop WPF application.
One of the inevitable steps of the scenarios is to select a folder with a windows folderbrowserdialog.

When I record this step with the automatic recorder, it appears that the engine create as many TreeItems as there are levels in the folder full path to be able to select the last TreeItem (which is the folder needed) and then click on OK button to let the application get the path of the selected folder.

I was wondering if there was an easier way or more elegant way to do this, like setting the full path in one go on any propertie of the browser window control?

Answer (score 0):

When I met standard windows dialog such as 'Open File', 'Save File' etc I usualy typed full path of desired location in 'File Name' textfield and then clicked OK. Fast and simple.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have no problem with a Browse for FILE popup where I can find the TextEdit field and that I already manage in the Coded UI Test of the software. Here I'm talking about a Browse for FOLDER popup where there is no visible textEdit but only TreeView. It's a classical problem and I know that there are some BrowseForFolder Extensions to manage displaying TextEdit for full path, but in my case for now developers have not planned to switch to this...